# adding list index into a another list of lists

Tags: python, list, loops, append

hey what I need to do is that I have the lists below:

```
g=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
h=[[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]]
```

and I need to get add the first index from list h into the list g. the results should be like list below:

```
g=[[1,2,3,10,14],[4,5,6,11,15],[7,8,9,12,16]]
```

and this what I have done so far but it's not working:

```
g=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
h=[[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]]
for i in range(len(g)):
   for u in range(len(g[0])):
      g[i].append(h[i][u])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
g=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
h=[[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]]

idx = 0
for L1 in g:
    for L2 in h:
        L1.append(L2[idx])
    idx+=1

g
```

Returns

```
[[1, 2, 3, 10, 14], [4, 5, 6, 11, 15], [7, 8, 9, 12, 16]]
```

Good luck!

Comment: Better use `enumerate`, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

another way:

making a zip object `hz` from `h` contents (`*h`), `next(hz)` auto increments as the list comprehension walks through `g`
`[*next(hz)]` (or `list(next(hz))`) converts the tuple from the zip object into a list

```
g =[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
h=[[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]]

hz = zip(*h)
g = [e + [*next(hz)] for e in g]

g
Out[133]: [[1, 2, 3, 10, 14], [4, 5, 6, 11, 15], [7, 8, 9, 12, 16]]
```

and for some the goal is a 'one-liner':

```
g = [e + list(f) for e, f in zip(g, zip(*h))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `enumerate()` and list comprehension, you can do a faster one-liner:

```
g = [n + [m[i] for m in h] for i, n in enumerate(g)]
# Returns: [[1, 2, 3, 10, 14], [4, 5, 6, 11, 15], [7, 8, 9, 12, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the outer loop over h instead of g. No indexes needed.

```
>>> g = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> h = [[10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]]
>>> for hlist in h:
        for glist, hvalue in zip(g, hlist):
            glist.append(hvalue)

>>> g
[[1, 2, 3, 10, 14], [4, 5, 6, 11, 15], [7, 8, 9, 12, 16]]
```

In other words: Instead of taking each g-list and fetching additional values from the h-lists, take each h-list and spread its values over the g-lists.